# How to insert CSV Column values into block and Table using Oracle Forms?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am using Oracle Database 11gR2 with Oracle Forms and Reports 11gR2.

I created "Browse" Button with "TEXTFIELD". When button press then open dialog box and select "csv" file and "csv" path file will be appear in "TEXTFILED". For this purpose I used "AWTFileDialog.jar" File.

Now I want "CSV" Column values shown into Block and also data save into table when "SAVE" Button pressed.

My Form:

[image]

How to achieve this target?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do that using Forms. I'm also not sure I'd do it using Forms.

But, I have two other options:

- SQL*Loader
- external table (which, in the background, also uses SQL*Loader)

The first option, **SQL*Loader**, requires you to create a control file (see the documentation, here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_concepts.htm#g1013706). As it is invoked from command prompt (on a **client** computer), you'd use HOST (if you're on Forms 6i) or CLIENT_HOST (Webutil) if you're on higher versions to call a batch script which contains the SQLLDR.EXE call.

Another option, **external table**, works on the database server, as you have to have access to the directory (Oracle object) (i.e. granted read/write privileges on it). As external table represents the input (CSV) file just as if it was an "ordinary" Oracle table, you can write `SELECT` against it and load data into the target table quite easily.

See if any of those options help, or wait for someone else's opinion.